# StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

I am extremely new to TensorFlow and I am trying to run [this](https://github.com/alexisbcook/ResNetCAM-keras) keras implementation of Class Activation Map on ResNet50. But I get the below error and I couldn't get the output. I don't understand the error message and how to resolve it. I searched but couldn't find potential solutions. Can you help solve this error and get the output image.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe you should change to another machine with gpu.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ? I know its been 2 years...